# syntaxerror in euclid.py in python 3.4

Tags: python, package, python-3.4

I've done some reinstalling lately and It seems I've broken my python 3.4 installation.

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/euclid.py", line 137
    raise AttributeError, name
                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Do you have any idea what packages should I reinstall?

Comment: Seems like `euclid` would be a prime candidate. . . It's using the old style of `raise` (which should never be used in new code).  `raise AttributeError(name)` should be used instead. . . With that said, I'd expect 2to3 to handle this one. . .

Comment: I am getting this. I am starting to be irritated. Do you know how can one absolutely reinstall whole python 3.4? 

2to3 euclid.py
bash: /home/snurkabill/miniconda/bin/2to3: /home/snurkabill/miniconda/bin/python: bad interpreter: No such file or directory

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem when I tried to install `euclid` via `pip3`. I've downloaded the source from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/euclid and changed all the `raise AttributeError, xyz`, messages to `raise AttributeError(xyz)` like proposed by @mgilson in his comment. Then installing with `python3  setup.py install` worked fine.

P.S. I've uploaded the updated `euclid.py` to github:
https://github.com/makemate/euclid_package